# iOS Restkit how to relate entities in mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit, relationship

I have 2 entities: Article and Category.

```
//Article mapping
RKManagedObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class] inManagedObjectStore: objectManager.objectStore];
categoryMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"categoryId";
[categoryMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"CategoryId",@"categoryId",
 @"CategoryName",@"categoryName",
 nil];

//Category mapping
RKManagedObjectMapping *articleMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class] inManagedObjectStore: objectManager.objectStore];
articleMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"articleId";
[articleMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"ArticleId",@"articleId",
 @"ArticleName",@"articleName",
 @"ArticleText",@"articleText",
 @"CategoryId",@"categoryId",
 nil];

//relationship mapping
[categoryMapping mapRelationship:@"articles" withMapping:articleMapping];
[articleMapping mapRelationship:@"category" withMapping:categoryMapping];
[articleMapping connectRelationship:@"category" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"categoryId"];

//set mapping
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:articleMapping forKeyPath:@"article"];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:categoryMapping forKeyPath:@"category"];
```

then I want to know category of article, but it is equal to null:

```
   Article* article = [[Article allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   //article.category == nil
```

article.categoryId and category.categoryId are equal.

**Why mapping relationship not working?**

Comment: [categoryMapping mapRelationship:@"articles" withMapping:articleMapping];

[articleMapping mapRelationship:@"category" withMapping:categoryMapping];

[articleMapping connectRelationship:@"category" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"categoryId"];

this code is right?

Answer (score 0):

Try relationship mapping in this way

```
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"articles" toRelationship:@"articles" withMapping:articleMapping];  
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"category" toRelationship:@"category" withMapping:categoryMapping];
```

This is working perfect for me. I have used it in my two projects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do you define that article.categoryId is the same as category.categoryId?